# How to set UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed on a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to make a button appear disabled without actually disabling it.

I want the greyed out color.

The button is Type `Custom` in interface builder.
It has an image for the background.

I don't want to mess with image states, I simply want to change it to grey whenever I want in the same way that setting `myButton.enabled = NO` sets it to grey.

So I tried setting `someButton.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed` in my viewDidLoad, and even further into the app, and it's still appearing the typical bright blue color.

Is there some other property on the button I need to set/change in order to be able to control the tintAdjustmentMode myself?

I even tried my own button, using the following code, and that didn't work either.

```
@implementation TintableUIButton

    -(id)init
        {
            self = [super init];
            if (self) {
                self.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                self.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed;
            }
            return self;
        }

@end
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the UIButton color properties to the color of gray you are looking for. .tintColor / .titleColor etc.

Comment: @Daniel ~ That doesn't work either.  `myButton.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor]` does nothing.  Tint color is powerfully enforced throughout the hierarchy, and I'm trying to obtain an ounce of my own control over it.

Comment: Custom button does not obey tint. You will have to recolor the image yourself. Here's an example where I do this for the text of the button title. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch12p612tintColor/bk2ch12p612tintColor/MySpecialButton.swift

Comment: @matt.  Yes, it's looking like my only option is `myButton setImage:forState:` and just swap the precolored images.  Oh well.

Comment: Exactly the sort of thing I'm thinking of.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add a line of code on click event 
initially keep the button switchBool as false in viewdidload()

```
-(IBAction) btn_Action_Inside:(id)sender
{

    if (!switchBool) {

        [switchMap setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NormalImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        switchBool = true;
    }
    else if(switchBool)
    {

        [switchMap setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GrayedcolorImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        switchBool = false;
    }

}
```

Or you can opt for

```
-(IBAction)btn_Action_Inside:(id)sender
    {

        if (!switchBool) {

                self.yourButton.alpha = 1.0f;
                switchBool = true;
        }
        else if(switchBool)
        {

                self.yourButton.alpha = 0.5f;
                switchBool = false;
        }

    }
```

or you can opt this

```
-(IBAction)btn_Action_Inside:(id)sender
    {

        if (!switchBool) {


                [self.yourButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
                switchBool = true;
        }
        else if(switchBool)
        {

                [self.yourButton setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
                switchBool = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing `setImage:forState:` per the comment in my original post.  `setTintColor:` does not work as I and matt pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You can create a custom class and add  a method like:

```
class customBtnClass: UIButton {
     func fakeIsEnable(enable: Bool){
        if (enable){
            self.tintColor = .blue // your default tint
        }else{
            self.tintColor = .gray
        }
    }
}
```

[Drag a simple button and set the custom class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF5iB.png)

Create an IBOutlet and call the method

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnTest: customBtnClass!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btnTest.fakeIsEnable(enable: false)
}
```

Objective c:

```
-(void) fakeIsEnable:(BOOL) enable{
    if (enable){
        self.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // your default tint
    }else{
        self.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
}
```

In your ViewController (don't forget  #import "CustomBtnClass.h" )

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomBtnClass *yourButton;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.yourButton fakeIsEnable:NO];
}
```

Regards

Comment: Updated my answer above, this didn't work.  :(   I'm just going to swap the image out for a recolored one as needed.  I was hoping to use the tinting already built in when using `.enabled = NO` but it appears that functionality isn't available in the ways I've tried.